# Rails: Test pages that require login with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

Ok, I'm using [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) in my `User` model to automatically fill in the `:password_digest` field in my model.

I'd like to simulate a login in my `test_account_page.rb` integration test below, so that I can confirm that a logged in user can access the page at `account_path`.

```
test "a logged in user can access their account page" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

  # Sign in first
  visit signin_path
  fill_in 'email', with: @user.email
  fill_in 'password', with @user.password # <!-- this won't work
  click_button 'Login'

  # Then visit account page
  ...
end
```

This won't work because `@user.password` does not give us the password in plain text form (the whole idea of using `has_secure_password` in the first place is to make the original password unrecoverable).

So how do I test a page hidden behind the login screen when using `has_secure_password`?

Comment: How are you creating the user with FactoryGirl?

Comment: @Iceman it's not FactoryGirl. It's the `password`. If I pass the hashed password in the text field, then it gets hashed again .. and it won't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use user attributes like this:

```
test "a logged in user can access their account page" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @user_attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)

  # Sign in first
  visit signin_path
  fill_in 'email', with: @user_attrs.email
  fill_in 'password', with @user_attrs.password
  click_button 'Login'

  # Then visit account page
  ...
end
```

Comment: Filling in the hashed password into the `password` field will result in a failed login attempt. I don't have the password in plain-text form.